# Is it possible to set a custom template roscreate-pkg?

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to customize the behavior of roscreate-pkg so that it follows company defaults, urls, etc and I'm wondering if there's a "right" way to do this.

I suppose the obvious answer is that I could just store a template somewhere and use that instead of roscreate-pkg, but I'm hoping to avoid deviating from the standard workflow and code paths as much as possible.

Are the defaults for roscreate-pkg parameterized somewhere such that they can be easily customized?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29144/is-it-possible-to-set-a-custom-template-roscreate-pkg?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, they are not parameterized anywhere.  roscreate-pkg is a fairly simple tool right now.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1